# Pandas data frame not allowing me to drop first empty column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have read in some data from a csv, and there were a load of spare columns and rows that were not needed. I've managed to get rid of most of them, but the first column is showing as an NaN and will not drop despite several attempts. This means I cannot promote the titles in row 0 to headers. I have tried the below:

```
df = pd.read_csv(("List of schools.csv"))

df = df.iloc[3:]

df.dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace =True)

df.head()
```

But I am still getting this returned:

[image]

Any help please? I'm a newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve your read_csv() operation.

Avloss can tell your "columns" are indices because they are bold. Looking at your output, there are two things of note.

1. The "columns" are bold implying that pandas read them in as part of the index of the DataFrame rather than as values
2. There is no information above the horizontal line at the top indicating there are currently no column names. The top row of the csv file that contains the column names is being read in as values.

To solve your column deletion problem, you should first improve your read_csv() operation by being more explicit. Your current code is placing column headers in the data and placing some of the data in the indicies. Since you have the operation `df = df.iloc[3:]` in your code, I'm assuming the data in your csv file doesn't start until the 4th row. Try this:

```
header_row = 3 #or 4 - I am bad at zero-indexing
df = pd.read_csv('List of schools.csv', header=header_row, index_col=False)
df.dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace =True)
```

This code should read the column names in as column names and not index any of the columns, giving you a cleaner DataFrame to work from when dropping NA values.

Answer (score 0):

those aren't columns, those are indices. You can convert them to columns by doing

```
df = df.reset_index()
```